# Rospy and udp sockets

Tags: wireless, wifi, rospy, udpros, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to send data (x,y and yaw values) over UDP to a system that isn't running ROS (a myRIO or any other micro-controller)
I am using a code written in in python (ROSpy) by someone in else that processess the data from the camera.
What I have read online is that I can't send data over udp. Can I not create a socket [like this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication)?

If not, is it possible to change the code from python to c++ so that I can use UDP?

I'm sorry if the question seem stupid but this is my first experience with python and ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266788/rospy-and-udp-sockets/) by [Muda](https://answers.ros.org/users/31121/muda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-19**:\

> What I have read online is that I can't send data over udp.

Without knowing where you've read this or why that is claimed this is a bit of a dangerous statement, but I would say that is untrue.

There is no magic to `rospy`, ROS Python programs are just regular programs, so UDP should work.

**Comment by [Muda](https://answers.ros.org/users/31121/muda/) on 2017-07-19**:
This is from #q28322.

I understand that they are normal codes, that is why I am confused.

If I post a code would you be able to have a look at it quickly, (the code is only 49 lines)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That question is specifically about whether the `rospy` and `rosjava` *client libraries* (ie: the Python and Java code that implements the ROS networking and other infrastructure parts) can use UDP.

It is not about whether general use of UDP is possible in `rospy`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Muda](https://answers.ros.org/users/31121/muda/) on 2017-07-19**:
I must of misunderstood the question. Thanks for clearing it up.

I'm going to assume that sending the data obtained by ROS using UDP is possible.

Thanks!!!!